# If $\text{gcd}(m, n) = d$, true that for $a, m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{m}}) = \mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{d}{nm}})$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

I've got a proof for this below but I'm not exactly sure if the result or the proof is correct or not. Thanks!

By Bezout's Identity, there exists integers $s, t$ such that $ms + nt = d$. Then, $a^{\frac{d}{nm}} = a^{\frac{ms + nt}{nm}} = a^{\frac{t}{n} + \frac{s}{m}} = (a^{\frac{1}{n}})^{n} \cdot (a^{\frac{1}{m}})^{s} \in \mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{m}})$, so $\mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{d}{nm}}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{m}})$ since it is the smallest field containing $a^{\frac{d}{nm}}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $d \mid m$, there exists some integer $k > 0$ such that $m = dk$. Then, $a^{\frac{1}{n}} = (a^{\frac{d}{nm}})^{\frac{m}{d}} = (a^{\frac{d}{nm}})^{k} \in \mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{d}{nm}})$. We can do the same for $a^{\frac{1}{m}}$. So $\mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{d}{nm}}) \supseteq \mathbb{Q}(a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{m}})$.

Comment: Argument is fine, but there are a few typos. You should get $t/m+s/n$ in exponent instead of $s/m+t/n$.

Comment: Also note that under given conditions $q=mn/d $ is lcm of $m, n$ and hence we can write the field as $\mathbb {Q} (a^{1/q})$.